# How to pin image to screen in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

How can I pin an image to the screen like the profile picture in Snapchat on the top left corner? What should I should learn?

[image]

Comment: Add it as a subview of the window?

Comment: You mean like UIWindow.addSubview(UIButton)?

Comment: Something like that. But obviously you can't directly add to `UIWindow` itself. You need an instance of it, which you can get by doing `(UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.window`.

Comment: Umm so I typed this and tried (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.window!.addSubview(signOutButton), its crashing :/

Comment: Where are you writing this line of code?

Comment: Adding it to the window is a bad idea in terms of handling the actions you needs with it. where will you write those functions in appDelegate? It's bad practice. You should use a container ViewController with different views sliding

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that they have used ContainerViews. ContainerView is a resizeable View which can itself contain a View Controller. So you can put a ContainerView inside a View Controller and pin the UIImageView to the View Controller (using Constraints) on top of the Container View. 
Make sure the UIImageView is in front of the ContainerView in the view hierarchy so it is visible.

Watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hl_Re_KLhcY) to get some idea about ContainerViews.